# Cannot load an array with numpy load()

Tags: python, numpy

I cannot load an array from a binary file. What am I doing wrong?

```
pic = imread('headey-640.bmp')
save('test.in.npy', pic)
f = open('test.in.npy','r')
A = load(f)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Comment: Please do not use images to show us your code. This way it is much harder for others to find you question.
Use the `code` blocks from the editor to nicely format your code and error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to open your file in binary mode:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
np.save("test.npy", x)

with open("test.npy", "rb") as npy:
    a = np.load(npy)
```